# Why is my fancybox not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

PLease find attached the code for a link that I am currently trying to change into a fancybox. I have tried everything I can but this fancybox will not start working for me! I have done lots of research and experimented and nothing has worked.

HTML LINK

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="group"  href="skype.html"><img src="skype.png" width="30" height="30" /></a>
```

USUAL CSS AND JQUERY LINK THAT ARE ALL LINKED AS I CHECKED THEM

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: My understanding of Fancybox is this: http://fancybox.net/

Is this what your trying to achieve with the Skype link? I'm not 100% sure what your trying to achieve

Comment: @CharlesAnthonyBrowne sorry I thought it was common knowledge, my apologies. But yes you are correct its fancybox.net. A jquery plugin :)

Comment: Only reason why I was unsure, is I'm not sure why you would want to add a fancybox effect on the skype.

Comment: Hi Charles, its just because I have several options for skype... eg call us, request call back, download skype etc @CharlesAnthonyBrowne

Comment: @CharlesAnthonyBrowne can you see why it won't work?

Comment: Oh. You're loading jquery after your fancybox, which overwrites what fancybox has already done. (you're loading 2 jquerys)

Comment: @Chad thanks man thats great, Ill just try and fix that:). If you want to right it as an answer ill tick the hell outta ya! hehe

Comment: See if it fixes it first.

Comment: @Chad your now shamazing tooo it worked! cheers my homeboy! hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is a site-specific issue. You're trying to utilize a couple of different libraries-- FancyBox and bxSlider (a personal favorite of mine)-- but you try to load jQuery twice.

You load:

```
jQuery1.10
fancyBox.js
jQuery1.11
bxSlider.js
```

You only need one instance of jQuery, so removing the 2nd request should take care of your issue.

Comment: that's the answer to a common mistake